# How to add an unanalyzed text keyword for sorting in elasticsearch with NEST?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the NEST client in C# to interact with my elasticsearch cluster.

I'm trying to sort based on a string value. But per [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html), I can't do that because the field is a text field.

So I want to add a keyword field and sort based on that for better performance. Something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to best translate that to the NEST client and then how to sort based on `my_field.keyword`.

I have this as my mapping, but since I'm not sure what the sort clause looks like, I'm not sure how to test it.

```
.Mappings(m => m
    .Map<Product>(mm => mm
        .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t
                .Name(n => n.ProductName)
                .Analyzer("custom")
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Keyword(k => k)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I've been trying to dig through the NEST documentation, but this more edge functionality has been harder to find.

Comment: Mapping a `string` property with multiple fields and analyzers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html. Use the `.Suffix("<suffix_name>")` to reference for sorting

Comment: Thanks! That ended up working. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct, Russ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference a *sub*-field of a multi-field, you can use the `.Suffix("suffixname")` extension method within a member access lambda expression

```cs
client.Search<Comic>(s => s
    .Query(q=> q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Description.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Query("Wolverine")
        )
    )
);
```

which results in the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description.keyword": {
        "query": "Wolverine"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also specify the string if you prefer

```cs
client.Search<Comic>(s => s
    .Query(q=> q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("description.keyword"))
            .Query("Wolverine")
        )
    )
);
```